# I want to make a sum from 5 tables that have one column named "UP"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have 5 tables (bepd , tirpd , elpd , frpd , kopd) with the same column named "Up" , and i want to make the sum of Up from all tables and to show it in a php code . can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  sum(SumUp)
from    (
        select  sum(up) as SumUp
        from    Table1 
        union all
        select  sum(up)
        from    Table2
        union all
        select  sum(up)
        from    Table3
        union all
        ...
        ) SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: You're doing more sums than you need to.